# Wildfly 10 migration, IP binding issue

Tags: java, migration, ip, jboss5.x, wildfly-10

I have migrated from Jboss 5.1 to Wildfly 10 and the application coming up locally. I am not able to post any requests from VIP to Wildfly server. I tried setting

```
<interface name="public">
        <inet-address value="${jboss.bind.address:0.0.0.0}"/>
    </interface>
```

And also

```
<interface name="public">
        <any-address/>
    </interface>
```

But the IP is not getting binded.

```
tcp        0      0 :::8080                     :::*                        LISTEN      28773/java
```

When I give complete URI path of the server from another host I am able to post the requests.

I have also taken care of socket-binding-group, standard-sockets.

If I revert to Jboss 5 the requests are getting successfully posted and I see

```
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:8080                0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN
```

Any pointers appreciated.

Comment: Try to run with the command line options `-b 0.0.0.0` and see if that works.

Comment: I tried that too. Didn't work. Can it be because of IPv4 or IPv6 ?

Comment: binding IP address got resolved after including IPv4 -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true, but still facing issue with the VIP connection.

Answer (score 0):

What mode are you using wildfly? A quick tip, look what mode you are using the wildfly, if you are using standalone mode, you must define these configs in standalone.xml, otherwise if you are using domain mode, you must to define in domain.xml, in Domain Controller, first of all, give us this answer...

In addiction, if you are using a specific profile, for ex: ha, you have to define this public interface in xml referent to this profile in this example it is standalone-ha.xml... or if you have a generic xml file, you must to define in your profile specific module configution in order to your mode which wildfly will be started